# Unable to launch Chrome Desktop App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, desktop-application

1. I've created my first Chrome Desktop App from https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app
2. There is instruction to launch the application using parameter line **--load-and-launch-app=/path/to/app/** at the bottom section of the above help page.
3. So I created a Chrome shortcut and added the line **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --load-and-launch-app=/T:/Chrome Projects/Hello World"**
4. But unfortunately, it isn't working and giving error saying missing manifest though it isn't [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvmtH.png)
5. I can run the app normally if i execute it from chrome browser>Apps section
6. Also there is no issue if i run the app using ID **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --profile-directory="Profile 4" --app-id=geipneggnldmjggcpfhniohfnfnccopo**
7. The App is saved at the folder **T:\Chrome Projects\Hello World** on my system

Any help is much appreciated
Regards,

Comment: /T:/Chrome Projects/Hello World" is an invalid path in Windows. Try "T:\Chrome Projects\Hello World"

Comment: Hi wOXXOM, thanks for the reply. Sadly it's not working either.

Comment: Hi I found the it. it is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-and-launch-app="T:\Chrome Projects\Hello World"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct and full code is:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-and-launch-app="T:\Chrome Projects\Hello World"